# Issue with remote debugging in WebStorm + Nodemon

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, webstorm, nodemon

I am using Nodemon to speed up my development so it restarts my app when I do some changes.

As WebStorm debug is not working with Nodemon in standard way (`%NODE_DEBUG%` or `--debug-brk` does not trigger debugger properly), I found the way where I run `nodemon --debug-brk` and remote debugging session in WebStorm.

The issue which I got is that every time when nodemon restarts my app it hangs on (the app) until I will restart my remote debug and then it enters my entry JS file and then I can 'continue' and it works then. It is annoying and I have no idea how to set it up properly.

Is it either better way to set up Nodemon+WebStorm or somehow set WebStorm in a way when it will not loose connection to that debug session?

Comment: Node uses -inspect --inspect-brk now. 
See my answer at : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52463378/7350853

Answer (score 2):

> As WebStorm debug is not working with Nodemon in standard way
>   (%NODE_DEBUG% or --debug-brk does not trigger debugger properly)

WebStorm does allow debugging applications run with Nodemon using either **Node.js**

[image]

or **NPM** run configurations

[image]

> The issue which I got is that every time when nodemon restarts my app
>   it hangs on (the app) until I will restart my remote debug and then it
>   enters my entry JS file and then I can 'continue' and it works then.

Known issue, [WEB-25672](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25672)