# Node.js Debugging flow

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, byebug

I'd like to debug node.js like rails. 
I've tried several ways:

1. Webstorm debug – in this case I need to click "rerun debug" each time after code changed
2. Nodemon with chrome remote debugger – in this case I need to reconnect to debugger each time after code reloaded by nodemon
3. pry.js – here I need to type "eval(pry.it)" – and have no option to make it simpler like "debug" or pry()

So what's the best option to debug node apps like byebug for rails?

Upgrade:

Thx to @AbhinavD I've managed to do it in VSCode:
First you need to edit app/.vscode/launch.js
`javascript
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Node: Nodemon",
            "processId": "${command:PickProcess}",
            "restart": true,
            "protocol": "inspector",
        },
    ]
}`

So now nodemon restarts server after changes and VSCode reconnect to debugger automatically.

See video https://vimeo.com/267975071

Is anybody able to do it in WebStorm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how `byebug` works. However if you use VSCode and nodemon (installed globally), VSCode can reattach itself to the running process and will break at the same point in the debugger.

Here is what my config file looks like

```
{
      "name": "Launch server.js via nodemon",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeExecutable": "nodemon",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/joiValidation.js",
      "restart": true,
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
    }
```

Here is the [small video](https://youtu.be/aF2_g8QUTo0) I made from my debugging. [Official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging)

Comment: @Costa, I did not understand what do you mean here. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question: **There is no way**. Unfortunately, with Node.js, you always have to restart the debugging session when you change your code .

[I've recently written an article](https://hackernoon.com/debugging-javascript-typescript-node-apps-with-chrome-devtools-vs-code-and-webstorm-97b882aee0ad) about debugging both JavaScript and TypeScript using different tools, if you're interested, but there's nothing like live debugging.

Comment: Thanks for the link, André. I was looking for some debug options for Node.js debugging.

Comment: Thx u, that's sad(

Comment: Take a look at the upgrade, what do you think?

Answer (score 2):

### Now with the upgrade works just fine. [23/09/2018]

For configuration you need to have the Webstorm 2018.**2** and follow the steps below:

[image: webstorm run/debug configuration]

and **ALSO** include the option to "Attach to Node.js/Chrome" [+] as follow:

[image: webstorm run/debug configuration attach option]

To make the debugger restart after every change you would have to enable the [**x] Reconnect Automatically** option.

The flow of working with the debug is:

1. **Run** your (in my case) Nodemon.
2. **Debug** your (in my case) NodemonDebugger
3. Set the breakpoints and everything else and you are good to go.

> Note: If you are going direct to the debugger instead (and therefore
>   not following this process) one would probably be expecting a
>   termination of the process after changing the code lines.